# C# solution "Apache PDFBox Remove Spaces between characters"

Tags: c#, pdfbox

Thanks, I am new to PDFBox & am having the same issue as described in "[[Apache PDFBox Remove Spaces between characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554400/apache-pdfbox-remove-spaces-between-characters][1])"

Is there an equivalent solution in C#?

Comment: For a solution I willing to paypal $20 to you

Answer (score -1):

I moved from PDFBox to iText. Problem solved.